# jquery.Coundown styling issues

Tags: jquery, css

I am having a hard time with the JqueryCountdown scripts styling.  Here is what is occuring visualy...
[image: What isn't working]

Here is how it looks running out of visual studios debugger
[image: How I want it to look]

I want the style to look more like the second one then the first.  I am not very good at css stuff.  But I did try.  I did briefly look at the css file that came with the download.
It seems fine... 
Here is my sites css for the countdown form element...

```
form .counter
{
   position: relative;
   right:-50;
   top:5px;
   font-size:12px;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#ccc;
}
```

What can I do to make sure that the element at least looks presentable?

**EDIT**  I JUST NOTICED HOW HARD IT WAS TO SEE WHAT MY PROBLEM WAS IN THE BOTTOM RIGHT HAND CORNER I HAVE SOME TEXT... I WANT THAT TEXT TO BE DIRECTLY BELOW THE TEXT AREA...
Here is an example of what aint right!
[image: A little clearer here]

A little bit clearer.

Comment: argh Internet Explorer o_O My poor eyes!

Comment: put a `<br />` between your `textarea` and your "Characters left" label ?

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML of your page? I don't see why a break wouldn't work as Cyrille mentioned. How about display:block for the counter style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relative and/or inline positioning of your jQuery Countdown element is likely the problem. Try changing your CSS to the following:

```
.counter {
    color: #ccc;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If you feel the need to add more separation between the comments and the character counter, use a generous amount of `margin-top` applied to the `.counter` or `margin-bottom` applied to the `<textarea>`.